# Windows 7 Pavilion - White ares with vertical, pink, flickering pixels - Green areas with green, vertical moving pixels

Tags: windows-7, colors, lcd, hp-pavilion, pixels

I have a windows 7 Pavilion, HP laptop that's been having issues for a month or so.

It started after the laptop fell from my bedside, around a 2 foot drop onto the corner near the vent fan, and cracked the bottom part of the casing. The crack doesn't go up into the plastic around the powerkey or keyboard, and stops at the top of the fan. I just discovered this crack a few minutes ago, however I think it could possibly have something to do with the issue?

On any white area, for instance this whole screen mainly, there are fast, flickering pink pixels that seem to be vertical. They move along with the color, across my whole screen. There are no black or unresponsive areas, therefore nothing is wrong with my screen it seems. It's practically the same on darker/black areas, with only green pixels in that case. This started as I said, after it had fallen off of my bed.

Whenever I have the laptop screen and tilt it down, the cracked plastic seems to be forced away, as it is broken, by the hinge mechanism of the screen, and then the screen turns into tons of black pixels and a dark gray screen, the image of whatever I was on, gone, until I stop moving the screen or tilt it back upwards into a near right angle, therefore relieving the tension on the plastic on the bottom.

If this bottom part of plastic, which is just the outer casing it seems, is the problem, or part of it, anyone know an estimate on cost? or if it would be worth getting fixed, or just investing in a new pc?

Thank you for reading, and I appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the screen itself is bust, the state of the plastic casing is more or less irrelevant so long as it isn't pointed inwards.

A screen replacement for an HP pavilion laptop should cost no more than £50 / $70 usd, plus the actual cost of installing the new screen, though you can do that yourself with a few tools and an online guide.

As for if it'd be worth getting it fixed? A new screen is a lot cheaper than a new laptop, so yes, it's worth it.